# Get name of the child component through ActivatedRoute or any

Tags: angular

Consider My router component is as below:

```
{
              path: 'abc-def-ghi',
              component: ExampleComponent,
              children: [
                {
                  path: ':type',
                  component: ViewComponent,
                  children:[{
                     path: '',
                     component: HomeComponent
                  },{
                     path:':id',
                     component: InformationComponent
                  }]
                }
              ]
            }
```

And consider ExampleComponent has router-outlet where page get loaded based on the url.

i route to abc-def-ghi/pet/1234 or abc-def-ghi/pet . When i do console.log(this.activatedRoute.component.name) on ExampleComponent , i only get ExampleComponent. I don't get the child component. Is there a way to get the name of the actual child component loaded?

Comment: route.snapshot.firstChild does this work ?

Comment: @DhavalPatel I kinda tried     console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.firstChild.routeConfig.component.name);
and i was able to receive the name of child component.

Comment: great,  Can you please post the answer so that will be useful someone else :)